# How to pass a data member value to private object inside parent object?

Tags: php, class, object

This is the class that I save data:

```
class AA{
    public $a
    public $b
    private $_obj;
    public function __constructor(){

           }
    public function populate(){
           $data = //a query to get all data I need at once including $b
           $this->a = $data->a;
           $this->b = $data->b;
           }
    public function save() {
           if ( $this->_obj instanceof BB ) {

            $this->_obj->save() // $b is a value need to be manipulated in $_obj, it's saved there.
           }

          $data=array();// save all date excluding $b
          update_data($data);

        }
}
```

I prefer not to run a separate query for $b when populating class BB because the query in class AA already get the data. How to pass the value to class BB?

Comment: If `$b` is something that should be processed by `BB` object, why don't just make it its settable property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data to $_obj some way or another. What is the preferred way depends on the relation between both objects. If eg. AA is an extension of class BB you can just share the variable data by extending class BB (`class AA extends BB { }`). But if BB is, another example given, an interface of some sort (not the programatical interface keyword) you should pass the data to BB. Than do something like this:

```
private $_data = null;

...

public function populate() {
    $data = //a query to get all data I need at once including $b
    $this->_data = $data;
    ...
}

public function save() {
    ...
    $this->_obj->save($this->_data); // function to process the data
    ...
}
```

But yet again, this is more a design question than a pragmatical question. Your code is to abstract to answer this question intelligently.

Comment: BB is a small object that has not much business to do with AA, but they provide services to the same project. the data must be passed at populating phase, because BB need to do something with data before arrive save(),